# Select checkbox with name[] and values (jquery/javascript)

Tags: jquery, json, forms, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I'm saving a form as a json object which I use to rebuild the form when refreshing or revisiting the page. It works well except that i'm having problems targeting checkboxes with "[]" after their name attributes.

My object: `{"product":{"checkboxname":["value1","value2"]}}`

```
// Reset form values from json object
$.each(formStateObjects[presentFormElementID], function(name, val){

    var $el = $('[name="'+name+'"]');
    var type = $el.attr('type');

    switch(type){
        case 'checkbox':
            $el.attr('checked', 'checked'); // Only works for checkboxes with unique name
            break;
        case 'radio':
            $el.filter('[value="'+val+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            break;
        default:
            $el.val(val);
    }
});
```

I need to change my checkbox selector somehow, or make a new one just for checkboxes with shared names. But I can't figure out how.

---- Edit: Updated my code -----------------------------------------

I made it work with the following code, although now it doesn't make sure that the right name is checked.

```
// Reset form values from json object
$.each(formStateObjects[presentFormElementID], function(name, val){

    var $el = $("[name=" + name + "]");
    var type = $el.attr('type');


    // If we have a checkbox name with many values
    if(val instanceof Array) {
        checkboxArrayValues = val;
        $.each( checkboxArrayValues, function( intValue, currentValue ) {
            // Refine the selector checking for name
            var $hit = $("[value=" + currentValue + "]");
            $hit.prop('checked', true);
        });
    }

    switch(type){
        case 'checkbox':
            $el.prop('checked', true);
            break;
        case 'radio':
            $el.filter('[value="'+val+'"]').prop("checked", true);
            break;
        default:
            $el.val(val);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply wouldn't this work?

```
$.each(formStateObjects['product'], function (name, val) {
    var $el = $('[name^="' + name + '"]');
    var type = $el.attr('type');

    switch (type) {
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]' ? [].map.call(val, function(val){
                $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', true);
            }) : $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', true);
            break;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/25Cn5/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work when the names of the checkboxes are in the format of name[].

That was my issue, for checkboxes with a unique name per checkbox, the code works.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/25Cn5/

Comment: Yeah that works, although it feels risky since now it doesn't look for an exact match anymore. See: http://jsfiddle.net/kLyq3/

I tried doing this for an exact match:

var $el2 = $("[name=" + name + '[]' +"]");

But that's not a valid selector somehow.